# A counterexample to [LM:K] = [L:K] [M:K]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I can't find a solution for the following task:

Let $F/K$ be a finite dimensional field extension with intermediate fields $L$ and $M$.

Use a real and non-real cube root of 2 to give an example where $L \cap M = K$ and $[L:K]=[M:K]=3$ ,but $[LM:K]<9$.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: The problem practically gives away the answer. Let $K$ be the rationals, let $F$ be the extension containing all three cube roots of 2, let $L$ and $M$ each contain one cube root of 2. Now, work out the details.

Comment: The problem also is solved by reading [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147753/if-k-leq-l-m-leq-e-are-fields-and-lmk-lkmk-infty-then-l-cap-m-k).